# Binding datasource to Barseries

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am attempting a telerik barseries control to plot some data. This is only my sample and I cant get it to working. I followed the examples available and read about data binding and still cant get to why this is not working for me.

Here is what I have done.

Define a basic class:

```
    public class CountClass
    {
        private int count;
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name
            }
            set
            {
                name= value;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
            set
            {
                count= value;
            }
        }

        public CountClass(string tempname, int value)
        {
            name = tempname;
            count = value;
        }
    }


public class QClass : Telerik.Windows.Controls.ViewModelBase
{
    private CountClass q1;
    private CountClass q2;

public QClass()
        {
        }

    public CountClass Q1
    {
        get
        {
            q1 = new CountClass ("Count1", 100);
            return q1;
        }
    }

    public CountClass Q2
    {
        get
        {
            q2 = new CountClass ("Count2", 200);
            return q2;
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
this.DataContext = new SilverlightApplication2.QClass();
```

And xaml:

```
<chartView:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Q1}"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
    FontSize="10"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to a `List` (or any other collection) even if it contains only one item.

```
public List<CountClass> Q1List {get{...}}
```

And your binding:

```
<chartView:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Q1List}" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That helped. I updated to this. Atleast now, the Q1List is recognized in the xaml, but I see no barseries plotted and its not the values I set in Q1List. I see the vertical axis name I set and number one on the horizontal, but not the values in Q1List. Anything else I need to set here?

Comment: It seems like its displaying the count of list items in the Q1List, but not the data itself.

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks for your help.